# Proving that the electronic Schrödinger equation has no closed analytic solutions for >1 electron

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation, electrons, many-body, quantum-chemistry

It is stated in many books that analytic closed solutions to the time-independent electronic Schrödinger equation,
$$\hat{H}\Psi = E\Psi, $$
 exist for the one-electron problem (e.g. hydrogen atom, assuming separability of nuclear and electronic motion) but that such solutions do not exist for systems with more than one-electron and thus approximation methods are required to solve the equation.

Specifically, on going from a one-electron system to a two-electron system, with fixed nuclei, something changes that makes closed analytic solution of the equation no longer possible.

Clearly this is related to the inter-electronic interaction because closed analytic solutions are possible for systems of non-interacting particles. 
Many resources suggest that the many-electron problem is "too difficult" to solve analytically but do not give any further details. This raises the question: is it the case that closed analytic solutions *cannot* exist, or that they could exist, but it is very difficult to find them? And, if they cannot exist, then how is this determined?

Comment: A lesson from recent history: http://arxiv.org/abs/1203.5408

Comment: I've come across a book called "Beautiful models 70 years of exactly solved quantum many-body problems". Probably you can find some clue there.

Comment: Really important fact: "closed-form" and "analytic" as used colloquially are basically meaningless. What you mean is "subjectively simple expression in terms of functions that I like." Is the sine function closed-form? It is if you say it is, it isn't if you say it isn't. After all, sine is only computable in the limit of infinitely many arithmetic operations, but we gave it a special name. So perfectly well-defined solutions to well-posed differential equations can be non-"analytic" to some simply because no one bothered to give those solutions a special name.

Answer (score 3):

A more precise mathematical way of asking your question is: given a (usually unbounded) self-adjoint operator $H$ on a Hilbert space $\mathscr{H}$, am I able to characterize its spectrum?

Finding "closed" solutions to the equation you are writing, means finding eigenfunctions of your operator $H$, possibly belonging to the Hilbert space $\mathscr{H}$ (since you want them to be realizable states). In other words it means that you investigate whether the operator $H$ has discrete spectrum.

Sometimes it is possible to prove that the spectrum is entirely discrete, sometimes that there is no discrete spectrum, but usually you have both discrete and non-discrete (essential) spectra: it really depends on the form of the operator $H$. There is an ongoing, huge and well established field of mathematical research on this subject called "spectral theory". The "bible" of mathematical physics, i.e. the books of Reed and [Simon](http://store.elsevier.com/product.jsp?isbn=9780125850506), dedicate an entire volume (the fourth) on this subject. I suggest you read the chapters VI, VII and VIII of the first volume as a general introduction, and whatever you like of Volume 4 (especially sections on bound states and eigenfunctions) to get an idea of the mathematical difficulties of analyzing the spectrum of operators, and consequently their eigenfunctions.